# iOS 8 Splash images after app launch

Tags: ios, webview, ios8, splash-screen

Let me start by saying that what follows I know is frowned upon by Apple, and would get rejected by the App Store if submitted. This is a non-issue as this will not be submitted in anyway. It is a internal app.

With that out of the way now. I need some help in setting if, else and else if statements. Before the migration to the iPhone 6 and 6+, my current code works for iPhone5/5s and below screen sizes in loading and sending the right image after the app launch.

My goal here is to include the iPhone 6/6+ into this equation.

Below is the relevant code pertaining to doing this.

This loads the images to the proper screen size.

```
    //Setting Splash Images
#define IS_IPHONE (!IS_IPAD)
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)

    bool isiPhone5 = CGSizeEqualToSize([[UIScreen mainScreen] preferredMode].size,CGSizeMake(640, 1136));
    if (isiPhone5) {

        // Load iPhone 5 Splash
        UIImage *splash4Inch = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h@2x.png"];
        self.splash4InchPortrait = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 568.0f)];
        [self.splash4InchPortrait setImage:splash4Inch];
        [self.view addSubview:self.splash4InchPortrait];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.splash4InchPortrait];
        self.splash4InchPortrait.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    }

    else if (IS_IPAD) {
        // Load IPad Splash
        UIImage *splashPad = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Portrait~ipad.png"];
        self.splashPadPortrait = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 768.0f, 1024.0f)];
        [self.splashPadPortrait setImage:splashPad];
        [self.view addSubview:self.splashPadPortrait];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.splashPadPortrait];
        self.splashPadPortrait.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    }

    else {
        // Load the iPhone 3.5" Splash
        UIImage *splash35Inch = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
        self.splash35InchPortrait = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
        [self.splash35InchPortrait setImage:splash35Inch];
        [self.view addSubview:self.splash35InchPortrait];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.splash35InchPortrait];
        self.splash35InchPortrait.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    }
```

This hides/unhides said images depending on what screen size is loaded.

```
//Get screen size
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){
    //DO Portrait
    if (screenBounds.size.height <=480) {
        //code for 3.5-inch screen
        splash35InchPortrait.hidden = NO;
        splashRetina35InchPortrait.hidden = YES;
        splash4InchPortrait.hidden = YES;

    }else{
        // code for 3.5 Retina inch screen
        splashRetina35InchPortrait.hidden = NO;
    }

}else{
    // code for 4-inch screen
    splash35InchPortrait.hidden = YES;
    splashRetina35InchPortrait.hidden = YES;
    splash4InchPortrait.hidden = NO;

}
```

This is the finish up code as the image is fading out.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview {

#define IS_IPHONE (!IS_IPAD)
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)

    bool isiPhone5 = CGSizeEqualToSize([[UIScreen mainScreen] preferredMode].size,CGSizeMake(640, 1136));
    if (isiPhone5) {
        // Loading iPhone 5
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        NSLog(@"didFinish: %@; stillLoading:%@", [[webView request]URL],
              (webView.loading?@"NO":@"YES"));
    }
    else if (IS_IPAD) {
        // Loading IPAD
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        NSLog(@"didFinish: %@; stillLoading:%@", [[webView request]URL],
              (webView.loading?@"NO":@"YES"));
    }
    else {
        // Loading iPhone 3.5"
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        NSLog(@"didFinish: %@; stillLoading:%@", [[webView request]URL],
              (webView.loading?@"NO":@"YES"));
    }

}
```

As you can see, I have it working to the best of my ability. I need to add the 6/6+ code.

Or if anybody knows a better simpler way of doing this, I'm all ears.

The main goal is preventing the white flash after the app loads. I have tried delaying the startup, but since my app is mainly webview, it doesn't help at all.

Thanks for reading, and the help.

Comment: why not use standard things to do the splash screen? why you do it in programm?

Comment: Ok, i thought I made that part clear. In any case. What I'm trying to do/have done is load images after the app launch. Essentially its a delay effect while the initial webview loads. This avoids the white flash of the screen which can be annoying. I understand that you can use the asset catalog to load images from resources and also create a Launch File with a nib or xib holding these images. But doing that my issue remains. The code above is in the view controller already, so when my app launches, it calls that code, shows the images and then fades out once my webview loads. Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so circling back to this. I I have everything how I want it. Delay is gone, all images added, even managed to remove the dedicated view controller calling these images. No nibs, xibs or storyboards.

How my app is set up now. I have a left side drawer, if i hit a cell it would have loaded that view but calling the splash screen again. Not ideal. But now it's perfect.

Here's what I did.

In my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

//Removing splash screen user default on app launch 
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"" forKey:@"Splash"];

    [self.window setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

View controller:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        //Splash Screen View Controller defaults
        if (![@"1" isEqualToString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Splash"]]) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"Splash"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

            self.splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
            [self.view setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
            [(UIImageView*)splashView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
            [self.splashView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
            [self.splashView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
            [self.splashView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [self.view addSubview:splashView];        
        }

    - (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation: (WKNavigation *)navigation {
        //Check here if still webview is loding the content
        if (self.webView.isLoading){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
        }

        else {
    //Splash Screen timer
            timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/1.0) target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        }
    }

    - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        [self.webView setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(didChangeOrientation:)
                                                     name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                                   object:nil];

        [self supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }

    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
        return YES;
    }

    - (void)didChangeOrientation:(NSNotification *)notification{
        [self setUpViewForOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
    }

    -(void)setUpViewForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

        //
        //Splash Screen Setup
        //
        CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
        CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
        if( screenHeight < screenWidth ){
            screenHeight = screenWidth;
        }

        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
            if (IS_IPHONE) {

                if (screenWidth == 480){
                    // iPhone 4/4s, 3.5 inch screen
                    UIImage *iPhone4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-700-Landscape@2x.png"];
                    [self.splashView setImage:iPhone4];
                    [self.view addSubview:self.splashView];
                    //NSLog(@"iPhone 4/4s");
                }
                if (screenWidth == 568){
                    // iPhone 5/5s, 4.0 inch screen
                    UIImage *iPhone5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-700-Landscape-568h@2x.png"];
                    [self.splashView setImage:iPhone5];
                    [self.view addSubview:self.splashView];
                    //NSLog(@"iPhone 5/5s");
                }
                if (screenWidth == 667){
                    // iPhone 6, 4.7 inch screen
                    UIImage *iPhone6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-800-Landscape-667h@2x.png"];
                    [self.splashView setImage:iPhone6];
                    [self.view addSubview:self.splashView];
                    //NSLog(@"iPhone 6");
                }
                if (screenWidth == 736){
                    // iPhone 6+, 5.5 inch screen
                    UIImage *iPhone6Plus = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-800-Landscape-736h@3x.png"];
                    [self.splashView setImage:iPhone6Plus];
                    [self.view addSubview:self.splashView];
                    //NSLog(@"iPhone 6 Plus");
                }
            }

            else if (IS_IPAD) {
                if ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 1){
                    // iPad 2
                    UIImage *iPad = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-700-Landscape~ipad.png"];
                    [self.splashView setImage:iPad];
                    [self.view addSubview:self.splashView];
                    //NSLog(@"iPad");
                }
                if ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2) {
                    UIImage *iPad = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-700-Landscape@2x~ipad.png"];
                    [self.splashView setImage:iPad];
                    [self.view addSubview:self.splashView];
                    //NSLog(@"iPad");
                }

            }
        }
        else {
            if (IS_IPHONE) {

                if (screenHeight == 480){
                    // iPhone 4/4s, 3.5 inch screen
                    UIImage *iPhone4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-700@2x.png"];
                    [self.splashView setImage:iPhone4];
                    [self.view addSubview:self.splashView];
                    //NSLog(@"iPhone 4/4s");
                }
                if (screenHeight == 568){
                    // iPhone 5/5s, 4.0 inch screen
                    UIImage *iPhone5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-700-568h@2x.png"];
                    [self.splashView setImage:iPhone5];
                    [self.view addSubview:self.splashView];
                    //NSLog(@"iPhone 5/5s");
                }
                if (screenHeight == 667){
                    // iPhone 6, 4.7 inch screen
                    UIImage *iPhone6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-800-667h@2x.png"];
                    [self.splashView setImage:iPhone6];
                    [self.view addSubview:self.splashView];
                    //NSLog(@"iPhone 6");
                }
                if (screenHeight == 736){
                    // iPhone 6+, 5.5 inch screen
                    UIImage *iPhone6Plus = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-800-Portrait-736h@3x.png"];
                    [self.splashView setImage:iPhone6Plus];
                    [self.view addSubview:self.splashView];
                    //NSLog(@"iPhone 6 Plus");
                }
            }

            else if (IS_IPAD) {
                if ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 1){
                    // iPad
                    UIImage *iPad = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-700-Portrait~ipad.png"];
                    [self.splashView setImage:iPad];
                    [self.view addSubview:self.splashView];
                    //NSLog(@"iPad");
                }
                if ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2){
                    UIImage *iPad = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage-700-Portrait@2x~ipad.png"];
                    [self.splashView setImage:iPad];
                    [self.view addSubview:self.splashView];
                    //NSLog(@"iPad");

                }
            }
        }
    }

    -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
        [self setUpViewForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
    }

    - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
        [self setUpViewForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    }

    //Image animation
    - (void)tick {
        if (!webView.loading) {
            [self performSelector:@selector(fadeimage) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
        }
    }
    -(void)fadeimage{
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [self.splashView setAlpha:0.0];
        [self.webView setAlpha:1.0];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

        [self.webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }
```

Pretty sure that's everything. Hope this helps somebody facing a similar issue.